# Array send by post form always received as string with first element only in Node js Express with pug

Tags: node.js, express, pug

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLaR9.png)

```html
{
  name: 'THERAPY 1',
  testsuites: '65e93cc4950e6a858809348f',
  description: 'UPDATED The pump software shall provide the Maximum Bolus Value therapy setting value upon request from the Pump Controller Interface.'
}
```

Browser send right array from form but server end req body has only first value as string.

tried with different online solution nothing work.

Please help me to figure out problem.

Comment: You need to share the code that handles this request, the code that sends it would be nice too. Also, share your main file where you set your body parsing middleware. For example, you need `express.urlencoded({extended:true})`